# Use $within with a buffered MondoDB Linestring

Tags: mongodb, geometry, geospatial, geojson

I need to evaluate the proximity of a `Point` to a `LineString` using MongoDB.

Because the `$near` operator can only compare a `Point` to another `Point`, I need to generate a polygon out of the `LineString`, so I can use the `$within` operator. The distance between the LineString and the edges of the polygon should represent the radius I want to search in, such as represented in red below:

[image: Polygon from Linestring]

What might be a useful algorithm in order to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you are looking for a buffer function, which MongoDB does not provide, so that you buffer the linestring by a certain amount and can then use geoWithin to find points that are inside you polygon?

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand your question, but it sounds like it, yeah!

Comment: A buffer means to grow by an equal amount in all directions, so a point would become a circle, and a line would become a polygon, as in your image above. MongoDB does not have a buffer function, so you will need to either load a spatial javascript library into MongoDB or convert you geojson outside of MongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think much easier would be to write your own function

To find (perpendicular) distance between point and line and then creating thickness of poly-line by polygon means.

[image: pnt line]

Where:

- `P0,P1` are line endpoints
- `P` is point
- `d` is distance between them

Line is defined as: `p(t)=P0+(P1-P0)*t` where `t=<0.0,1.0>`

So the function should do this:

1. **create perpendicular line**

   - `q(t)=P+DQ*u` where `u=(-inf,+inf)`
   - `DQ` is perpendicular vector to (P1-P0)

   In 2D you can obtain it easily like this `(x,y) -> (y,-x)`. In higher dimensions use cross product with some non coplanar vectors.
2. **compute line vs. line intersection**

   there are tons of stuff about this so google or solve the equation yourself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18739791/2521214) you can extract mine implementation.
3. **now after successful intersection**

   just compute `d` as distance between `P` and intersection point. Do not forget that parameter `t` must be in range. If not (or if no intersection) then `return min(|P-P0|,|P-P1|)`

**[hints]**

`t` and `u` parameters can be obtained directly from intersection test so if the perpendicular vector to `(P1-P0)` is normalized to `size = 1` then the `abs(u)` parameter of intersection point is the distance

**[notes]**

I am not familiar with **mongodb** so if you have no means to use own tests inside then this answer is of coarse obsolete.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. MongoDB only has basic spatial functionality, and lacks things like buffering a geometry. However, you can store Javascript functions on the server, run map reduce jobs, or run Javascript functions on the client (all with different cost/benefits). This would be easy to code up in JS.

Comment: I have implemented the method you describe above in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kalur/edit?css,js,output)

Comment: @Crunch the  `u=(-inf,+inf)` means that `u ` goes from -infinity to +infinity (whole Real numbers range) range `(a,b)` means that `a,b` are not included range `<a,b>` means that `a,b` are included

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MongoDB provides very basic geospatial query, so you should create the buffer by your own. You can read how to do it here: [Computing a polygon that surrounds a multi-point line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771908/computing-a-polygon-that-surrounds-a-multi-point-line)

If you have longitude/latitude coordinates like WGS84 you must adjust this code; Read here how to calculate distance between point on a sphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula